# Iterating nested json in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have JSON in this format. How can I print each value and go inside the objects. Also, the json can vary and also the name, so I need a generic solution.

```
output = {'name':'StackOverflow',
       'competitors':[{   'competitor':'bing',
                          'link':'bing.com'},
                      {   'competitor':'google',
                          'link':'google.com'}],
       'acquisition': {'acquired_day': 16,
                       'acquired_month': 12,
                       'acquired_year': 2013,
                       'acquiring_company': {'name': 'Viggle',
                                             'permalink': 'viggle'}}}
```

Comment: To clarify: you already have a dictionary, and you want to print all the values, including values in nested dictionaries, but not the keys? What is the expected output for your example?

Comment: I need to iterate through each key and value, replace all the values in the json with some other value.

Comment: You have to traverse over each key and value of your dict. Also have to check, if value is again dict, then do same.

Comment: That is different to what you asked for in your question...

Comment: Better option is, you can give example. This is what, and this is what you want

Comment: ...and what you have tried...

Comment: Can yo show an example how to check if value is a dict or not

Comment: One last try before I decide this is a waste of time: show the expected result.

Comment: `type(value, dict)` this will give, if value is dict or not.

Comment: for key,value in config.iteritems():
    print value

Answer (score 1):

You can use isinstance to check if something is a dict or a list. Something like this may work, but I haven't checked it.

```
output = {'name': 'StackOverflow',
      'competitors': [{'competitor': 'bing',
                       'link': 'bing.com'},
                      {'competitor': 'google',
                       'link': 'google.com'}],
      'acquisition': {'acquired_day': 16,
                      'acquired_month': 12,
                      'acquired_year': 2013,
                      'acquiring_company': {'name': 'Viggle',
                                            'permalink': 'viggle'}}}


def traverse(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.iteritems():
            print('dict_key', key)
            traverse(value)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for value in obj:
            traverse(value)
    else:
        print('value', obj)


traverse(output)
```

Comment: This works for the value but I would need keys as well as I would need to set that value with a new value